# webtoken is not working and I am getting jwt malformed error

Tags: javascript, jwt, postman

```
const isTokenIncluded = (req) =>{

        return req.headers.authorization || req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer : "); 
}

const getAccessTokenFromHeader = (req) =>{
    const authorization = req.headers.authorization;
    const access_token = authorization.split(' ')[1];
               
    return access_token;
}



const getAccessToRoute = (req,res,next) =>{

    const {JWT_SECRET_KEY} = process.env;
    if(!isTokenIncluded(req)){
        

        return next(new CustomError("You are not authorized to access this route",401));
        
    }

    const accessToken = getAccessTokenFromHeader(req);      
    
    jwt.verify(accessToken,JWT_SECRET_KEY,(err,decoded) =>{
        if(err){
            // return next(new CustomError("You are not authorized to access this route",401));
            return next(err);
        }
        console.log("decoded : " + decoded);
        next();
    });

    
}
```

Have a good day everyone.I am new to StackOverflow so sorry for if i have any mistake.I am trying to make question and answer `API`.Up to here,everything works good but in jsonwebtoken implementation,after trying this code in Postman I am encountering with `jwt malformed` error.The token and and cookies are working but I can't get the `decoded` value and program is giving authorization error.How can i fix this?

Comment: A simple `console.log(accessToken)` just before `jwt.verify(accessToken, ...` would easily show what`s going on. Malformed means that the token has not the form that is expected and in most cases it's a) because the token was not sent b) a mistake cutting it out of the Authorization header or c) it's no JWT.  So please add the console.log and let us know the result (as an [edit]) to your question). And btw., my guess is case b)

Comment: As you said the console showed nothing but only `::`.My postman authorization key is `Authorization` and the value is `Bearer : {{access_token}}` as defined in environmental value of postman.

Comment: Thanks to you I just changed the split value to the `split('  ')[2]` and the code worked.I think `split(' ')[1]` took only `:` in the Bearer value. Appreciated for your effort.

Comment: the correct Authorization header is `Authorization: Bearer <token>`. So there's just a space between the word "Bearer" and the token itself. In your code you then split by space, but as you have "Bearer : ..." the value you get from it is ":"

Comment: The correct solution is not to change the split command but the authorization header!